# Python manual call to descriptor ignored

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, methods, descriptor

```
class B(object):
    def meth(self):
        pass

class C(B):
    pass

b = B()
c = C()

print c.meth.__get__(b, B)
```

gives me:

```
<bound method C.meth of <__main__.C object at 0x10a892910>>
```

but I expect something like:

```
<bound method B.meth of <__main__.B object at 0x?????????>>
```

Why is my manual call to `c.meth.__get__` ignored? Python behaves as if I wrote `print c.meth`, and that lookup is automatically transformed to `print c.meth.__get__(c, C)`

Comment: `c.meth` is a bound method object. I'm frankly surprised it has a `__get__` method of its own. There's no reason to expect it works the same way as a descriptor that the original function object did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you get when you lookup `c.meth` is a descriptor, but perhaps not the descriptor you were expecting. Rather, it's the *result* of a descriptor call (which just happens to be another kind of descriptor). Specifically, `c.meth` is an `instancemethod` object. It's what you get when a function (e.g. `B.__dict__["meth"]`) gets invoked as a descriptor (e.g. `B.__dict__["meth"].__get__(c, C)`, which I suspect is the descriptor call you actually wanted to try for yourself).

The behavior of an `instancemethod` object when used as a descriptor is a bit odd. Unbound methods will bind if the class passed to `__get__` is a subclass of the method's original class, otherwise the unbound method will be returned as is. Already bound methods will never be rebound.

You're trying to bind an already bound method, which doesn't work. Specifically, `c.meth.__get__(b, B)` returns the same `instancemethod` object you had as `c.meth`. The extra `__get__` call is deliberately treated as a no-op.

You can see the implementation of the `__get__` method on bound methods in the cpython source code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/classobject.c#l2607). It's not very long, so I'll reproduce it:

```
static PyObject *
instancemethod_descr_get(PyObject *meth, PyObject *obj, PyObject *cls)
{
    /* Don't rebind an already bound method, or an unbound method
       of a class that's not a base class of cls. */

    if (PyMethod_GET_SELF(meth) != NULL) {
        /* Already bound */
        Py_INCREF(meth);
        return meth;
    }
    /* No, it is an unbound method */
    if (PyMethod_GET_CLASS(meth) != NULL && cls != NULL) {
        /* Do subclass test.  If it fails, return meth unchanged. */
        int ok = PyObject_IsSubclass(cls, PyMethod_GET_CLASS(meth));
        if (ok < 0)
            return NULL;
        if (!ok) {
            Py_INCREF(meth);
            return meth;
        }
    }
    /* Bind it to obj */
    return PyMethod_New(PyMethod_GET_FUNCTION(meth), obj, cls);
}
```

Comment: By saying "Unbound methods will bind if the object is a subclass of the method's original class, ..." Do you mean "Unbound methods will bind if the **class** is a subclass of the method's original class, ..."?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's more precisely correct than what I intended to say. I was thinking "if the object is *an instance of* a subclass" (but I left out the "instance" bit), but looking at the code it actually checks the `cls` argument rather than `type(obj)`. I'll edit to be more clear.